# Ratio of parts of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image: Diagram]

In the diagram above, segment DE is parallel to segment BC and the ratio of the area of triangle AED to the area of trapezoid EDBC is 1:2.

How can I find the ratio of AE to AC?

So far, I got the following:

- $\Delta ADE$ ~ $\Delta ABC$
- $\frac{Area \Delta ADE}{Area \Delta ABC}$ = $\frac{AE^2}{AC^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, find the ratio between the area of $ADE$ and the area of $ABC$:

$$S(ABC)=S(ADE)+S(EDBC)=S(ADE)+2S(ADE)=3S(ADE)$$

---

Then, use it in order to find the ratio between the length of $AE$ and the length of $AC$:

$$\frac{S(ADE)}{S(ABC)}=\frac13\implies\frac{AE}{AC}=\sqrt{\frac13}$$

Comment: Wow. I didn't even realize it was so simple. Thank you!

Comment: @Rex: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You have basically all the pieces you need, all you need to notice now is that the area of $\triangle ABC$ is the area of trapezoid $EDBC$ plus the area of $\triangle ADE$, so the area of $\triangle ABC$ is $3$ times the area of $\triangle ADE$ which gives you a final ratio of $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.